# Tense - will have understand / have understood / will understand

Tags: tense

Here's a context.

There is a quite big movement against colleage policy on campus that is about grading system. We used to get a score in absolute evlauation system, but policy has changed so we get to get a score in relative evaluation system. I have no idea which one is better than the other. And....

> 1. It will only be after I will have fully understood the system that I can judge the situation and conclude which one is better.
> 2. It will only be after I will fully understand the system that I can judge the situation and conclude which one is better.
> 3. It will only be after I've fully understood the system that I can judge the situation and conclude which one is better.

I think #1 is the best choice because it implies both 'future' and 'state after understanding'. Could you help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

3 is the only one which is grammatically correct (cf. [Present Perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html)).

The basic thing here is that you don't want to imply future twice--that would be 'in the future in the future', which is no good.  'I will only be able' already puts you in the future; the temporal part of the tense you should be using for the clause in question is the present.  1 and 2 are both future tenses and thus wrong.

Your future tenses are (now) formed correctly but cannot be used here because 'It will only be after' has already set the 'time' part of the tense so that the next verb must be in the present tense. 'I have fully understood' is the present perfect and 'I fully understand' is the simple present.  The present continuous tenses are also wrong (because of the word 'after'), but that's a different issue.

1-The error here is that you are trying to use a future tense.  This is the Future Perfect.

2-The error here is that you are trying to use a future tense.  This is the Simple Future.

3-This is okay.  "It will only be after I fully understand the system that I can judge the situation and conclude which one is better" is probably better because it uses the simple present (which is fine) instead of the present perfect and thus avoids needless complexity.

Note that 'that I can judge the situation and conclude...' as currently written is awkward; you may wish to reverse the order, resulting in "I will only be able to judge the situation and conclude which one is better after I fully understand the system."

Comment: Modified - understood